# Why is .mn file being generated?

Tags: scripting

I am running a Mathematica code inside a shell script, using `math -script <filename>.m`. But after the script finish its run, I get a duplicate (or backup?) file `<filename>.mn` . Why is such a file being generated? Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: I cant reproduce. You should provide system details, and check that this happens with a very simple script that you can post.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be related to the Global option for `AutoGeneratedPackage`.

From interactive Mathematica go to

```
Format -> Options Inspector
```

Use the pulldown to set ***Show option values*** to ***Global Preferences***

Select

```
Notebook Options -> File Options -> AutoGeneratePackage -> None
```

Comment: seems it does not work for me! :( Also could be any terminal option since I'm using it remotely?